# How to add an attribute "type" for default data type of elements in XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xsd

For Example :

### Input XML:

```
<employee>
     <name>Ragu</name>
     <city>Chennai</city>
     <age>25</age>
</employee>
```

Data type for above request xml element has been defined in request Schema file.
name is string, city is string and age is int data type.

### Output of transformation should be like:

```
 <employee>
      <name type="string">Ragu</name>
      <city type="string">Chennai</city>
      <age type="int">25</age>
   </employee>
```

Please anyone give the solution for this transformation. Thanks in Advance

Comment: `<name>Ragu</firstName>` is not well formed XML

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`document()`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_document.asp) function to read your schema, e.g.:

Input XML:

```
<employee>
    <name>Ragu</name>
    <city>Chennai</city>
    <age>25</age>
</employee>
```

Schema:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="employee">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="age" type="xs:int" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()">

        <xsl:variable name="type" select="substring-after(document('schema.xsd')
                              //xs:element[@name = name(current())]/@type, ':')"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:if test="$type">
                <xsl:attribute name="type">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$type"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>            
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces desired Output XML:

```
<employee>
    <name type="string">Ragu</name>
    <city type="string">Chennai</city>
    <age type="int">25</age>
</employee>
```

Comment: The XSLT given above is producing the Transformation Null.   And in the request any valid xml may come.

Comment: @Sabapathy, Did you specify right path to `schema.xsd` in XSLT?

Comment: @Sabapathy, What specifically does your XSLT-processor (BTW which?) output?

Comment: @Sabapathy, I can't tell about all XSLT engines, but in MSXML `document()` function isn't allowed by default. So mb you need to enable this option. And produce full text of message/error/exception.